# IE search input defaults

Tags: css, browser, input

I came across a little browser compatibility issue.
i have a search input field `<input type="search">`
and while in Chrome the height is exactly as i want it to be (30px),
the height in IE is always 2px more (32px)

heres the css code:

```
.search_field{
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #eeeeee;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0px;
}
.search_field:focus{
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #919191;
}
```

html:

```
<li>
    <b>Search</b><span style="float: right; font-size: 10px;">Advanced Search</span><br>
    <input type="search" class="search_field">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="search_input">
</li>
```

Are there any other IE defaults besides those i already tried to change?

Thanks!

Comment: No IE right now, have you tried adding `box-sizing:border-box` to `.search_field`?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other IE defaults besides those i already tried to
> change?

You can easily inspect your element style attributes using The IE Developer tool.
Just hit the <kbd>F12</kbd> key and inspect your input search field.

[image]

Click the arrow button inside of the Developer Toolbar window at the bottom of the screen and select which Element needs to be inspected by placing the cursor over the Element and then click on that Element

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because of border you are adding with it. So, **1px from top and 1px from bottom**, this way it's taking 2px more than it. Try fixing this once.

if not even this works, then you can add some css hacks like:

```
_height : 28px;  /* IE 6 */
*height: 28px; /* IE 7 */
```

Note: Keep this in mind that these are not valid css. I mean when you will validate it, it won't. Take reference: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS code, as suggested by @Passerby in a comment:

```
.search_field { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

The reason is that otherwise the `height` property specifies the *content* width, excluding padding and border, and the 1px borders above and below thus make the total height 30 + 1 + 1 pixels. The [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property can be used to override this.

Arguably, IE (and Firefox) is doing the right thing here, since the HTML5 CR says, in the section about [form field rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#form-controls), that in “standards mode”, an `input` element with `type=search` has normal CSS sizing, whereas in Chrome, it has `box-sizing: border-box` in the browser style sheet.